# jboss server root folder

Tags: jboss, root

how can i find which folder is the jboss root dir?

where can i find the root folder variable mentioned in a war file

Comment: What variable?  What root folder?

Answer (score 2):

IF you are looking for root folder that is right option. It would be 
/opt/jboss/jboss-as

But if you want to access anything (xml, file) at root directory say using 'http://ip:port/abc.xml' url you want to open abc.xml or any file, put that file in
`/opt/jboss/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war`

Answer (score 1):

The **root** folder of a JBoss AS installation is generally considered to be the `../jboss-as` folder...

For example if your deploy folder would be
`/opt/jboss/jboss-as/server/default/deploy`
the root folder would be
`/opt/jboss/jboss-as`

I don't know what you mean by the variable mentioned in a `.war` file.

Comment: But here, the `/opt` directory is empty. I've just installed `JBoss` server. No files/Programs are running. Is it possible to download any file just to place in  the root directory of `JBoss`?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the maven-war-plugin ,  can solve this issue very easily. If web.xml context-root didn't work  the plugin could move the application to the root of deployments on tomcat. Everything that isn't captured by a more specialized service is delegated to the application from web root /* to the web-app, :)

source : https://developers.openshift.com/servers/jbossas/deployment-options.html