# jboss URL for created file to download

Tags: java, pdf, jboss, applet

I'm stuck with the following Problem: I have an application running in jboss, creating a pdf. I want my remote client to print the pdf. Then the pdf will be deleted.

For the printing the [jPDFPrint](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfprint/) seems to be great, using a java [applet](http://www.qoppa.com/files/pdfprint/demo/applet.html).

But where do I need to store my pdf and how could I access it via an URL (http:// annotation)?

The application is all packed into a `*.ear`, so I figure, a place on the jboss server would be good to use, and those [paths](http://www.coderanch.com/t/473093/JBoss/app-access-server-conf-directory) are [available](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/dirs.html). But how to access that from file a remote client? How do I get it as a `http://..../file.pdf`?

Thank you!
Sura

Answer (score 0):

Store your file anywhere bellow the server root, that is in any subdirectory of server root.
Then you can "calculate" the address by "subtracting" server root path from file absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! Your answer led me to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655918/jboss-server-root-folder), where I find the solution in the second answer of it:

> But if you want to access anything (xml, file) at root directory say using 
>   `http://ip:port/abc.xml` url you want to open abc.xml or any file, put that file in 
>   `/opt/jboss/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war`

It is `.../deploy/ROOT.war` in my case and works well.